# How can I call/execute other functions within a Python programm

Tags: python

So, I have some trouble with my Python Script. Firstly how do I call another function within the same program. For example I have the function:

```
def Funktion1 ():
    a=(1-provision)*m
    b=(1-provision)*satmenge
```

and the Function

```
def Abfunktion ():
    c=a*2
```

how can I go from Funktion1 ():
directly to Abfunktion (): automatically.

The whole code is below:

```
Gewinn ():
    fixkosten=int(raw_input("Was sind die Fixkosten:"))
    einkaufspreis=int(raw_input("Die Variable Kosten"))
    propreis=eval(raw_input("Der Max preis:"))
    satmenge=int(raw_input("Wie viele verkaufst du"))
    provision=eval(raw_input("Wie viel bekommt der Haendler"))
    y=50002
#if fixkosten>0 and variablekosten>0:


def Steigung ():
        Propreis=eval(raw_input("Dein hoechster Preis:"))
        Satmenge=eval(raw_input("Wie viele leute werden es kaufen:"))
        if propreis >0 and satmenge >0:
                        m=(-1*Satmenge/Propreis)


def Funktion1 ():
    a=(1-provision)*m
    b=(1-provision)*satmenge

def Abfunktion ():
   c=a*2

def Nullstelle ():
    p=c/(-1*b)

def GewinnErgebniss ():
    gewinn=p*y-(fixkosten+p*y+provision*p*y)
    if gewinn<0:
        print("Dein verlust ist" ,gewinn , "I will not be investing,     I'M OUT!")
    else:
        print("Dein Gewinn ist" ,gewinn , "I think i'll make you an     offer")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "go to automatically".  You call other functions by... calling them -- `value = Funktion1()` -- though your functions have to return something for them to be useful, and none of your functions return anything, they also don't have any arguments.  I'm guessing you want the functions to set global variables, which is a terrible idea, but the functions aren't declaring the variables as `global` so they're not modifying the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I will try to answer what I think you are asking. You need to add return statements to your functions and pass values to them. For example,

```
def Funktion1 (provision, m, satmenge):
    a=(1-provision)*m
    b=(1-provision)*satmenge
    c = Abfunktion(a)
    return a, b, c

def Abfunktion (a):
    c=a*2
    return c

Funktion1(provision=1, m=2, satmenge=3)
```

will will execute Funktion1 and call Abfunktion.

I suggest you read more about how python functions wor [for example here](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code as follows for it to work. But as was mentioned above it is a very ugly solution since you declare a lot of variables that are used once in a global scope. Far more elegant solution will be to return variables from functions and use it as a parameters for the next functions in chain.

Basic solution:

```
#functions declaration
def Gewinn ():
    global fixkosten
    fixkosten=int(raw_input("Was sind die Fixkosten:"))
    global einkaufspreis
    einkaufspreis=int(raw_input("Die Variable Kosten"))
    global propreis 
    propreis=eval(raw_input("Der Max preis:"))
    global satmenge 
    satmenge=int(raw_input("Wie viele verkaufst du"))
    global provision 
    provision=eval(raw_input("Wie viel bekommt der Haendler"))
    global y
    y=50002
#if fixkosten>0 and variablekosten>0:


def Steigung ():
    Propreis=eval(raw_input("Dein hoechster Preis:"))
    Satmenge=eval(raw_input("Wie viele leute werden es kaufen:"))
    global m
    if propreis >0 and satmenge >0:
                    m=(-1*Satmenge/Propreis)

def Funktion1 ():
    global a
    a=(1-provision)*m
    global b
    b=(1-provision)*satmenge


def Abfunktion ():
    global c
    c=a*2


def Nullstelle ():
    global p
    p=c/(-1*b)


def GewinnErgebniss ():
    gewinn=p*y-(fixkosten+p*y+provision*p*y)
    if gewinn<0:
        print("Dein verlust ist" ,gewinn , "I will not be investing,     I'M OUT!")
    else:
        print("Dein Gewinn ist" ,gewinn , "I think i'll make you an     offer")


#actual place where functions are called
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Gewinn()
    Steigung()
    Funktion1()
    Abfunktion()
    Nullstelle()
    GewinnErgebniss()
```

More elegant solution:

```
#functions declaration
def Gewinn ():
    fixkosten=int(raw_input("Was sind die Fixkosten:"))
    einkaufspreis=int(raw_input("Die Variable Kosten"))
    propreis=eval(raw_input("Der Max preis:"))
    satmenge=int(raw_input("Wie viele verkaufst du"))
    provision=eval(raw_input("Wie viel bekommt der Haendler"))
    y=50002
    #return multiple values as a tuple
    return (fixkosten, einkaufspreis, propreis, satmenge, provision, y)

def Steigung (propreis, satmenge):
    Propreis=eval(raw_input("Dein hoechster Preis:"))
    Satmenge=eval(raw_input("Wie viele leute werden es kaufen:"))
    if propreis >0 and satmenge >0:
        m=(-1*Satmenge/Propreis)
    return m


def Funktion1 (m, satmenge):
    a=(1-provision)*m
    b=(1-provision)*satmenge
    return (a, b)


def Abfunktion (a):
    c=a*2
    return c


def Nullstelle (b, c):
    p=c/(-1*b)
    return p


def GewinnErgebniss (fixkosten, provision, p, y):
    gewinn=p*y-(fixkosten+p*y+provision*p*y)
    if gewinn<0:
        print("Dein verlust ist" ,gewinn , "I will not be investing,     I'M OUT!")
    else:
        print("Dein Gewinn ist" ,gewinn , "I think i'll make you an     offer")


#actual place where functions are called
if __name__ == '__main__':
    (fixkosten, einkaufspreis, propreis, satmenge, provision, y) = Gewinn()
    m = Steigung(propreis, satmenge)        
    (a, b) = Funktion1(m, satmenge)
    c = Abfunktion(a)        
    p = Nullstelle(b, c)
    GewinnErgebniss(fixkosten, provision, p, y)
```

So once again. In your script you have just defined a bunch of functions. You need to call it from somewhere. In my script I call it at the end of all definitions. And you have to make sure that all variables, that you defined in a function's local scope, are visible to other functions that want to use it. Common way to make it visible is to return it from your function.